# React Native Audio Animation

Tags: animation, audio, react-native, waveform

I am currently using [React Native Audio](https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio) to record audio and storing the sound. I am wondering if there is anyway to get the progress of this recording in realtime to map the microphone input to an animation, to give a visual feedback that the microphone is working.

Currently, the onProgress() function of the package only sends, from what I've found, only the current timecode.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I found a similar library which is not maintained anymore but it is still working fine.
https://github.com/prscX/react-native-siri-wave-view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am currently working on somthing similer.

That how i done it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Button,
    LayoutAnimation,
    Image,
    ScrollView,
    Animated
} from 'react-native';
export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        isPressed: false,
        animated: new Animated.Value(0),
        opacityA: new Animated.Value(1),
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._onPress = this._onPress.bind(this);
    }
    _runAnimation() {
        const { animated, opacityA } = this.state;

        Animated.loop(
            Animated.parallel([
                Animated.timing(animated, {
                    toValue: 1,
                    duration: 1000,

                }),
                Animated.timing(opacityA, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 1000,

                })
            ])
        ).start();
    }
    _stopAnimation() {
        Animated.loop(
            Animated.parallel([
                Animated.timing(animated),
                Animated.timing(opacityA)
            ])
        ).stop();
    }
    _onPress() {
        this.setState(
            state => ({ isPressed: !state.isPressed }),
        )
    }
    _micButton() {
        const { isPressed, animated, opacityA, } = this.state;
        if (isPressed) {
            //some function
            this._runAnimation();
            return (
                <Animated.View style={{
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    borderRadius: 50,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(153,0,0,0.4)',
                    opacity: opacityA,
                    transform: [
                        {
                            scale: animated
                        }
                    ]
                }}>
                    {/* icon or image */}
                </Animated.View>
            );
        } else {
            //some function
            return (
                <View style={{
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    borderRadius: 50,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(153,0,0,0.4)',
                }}>
                    {/* icon or image */}
                </View>
            );
        }
    }






    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}>
                    {this._micButton()}
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },

});
```

i hope that solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I use [expo-av](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/). There is an API [setOnRecordingStatusUpdate](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#parameters-1), you can set a function that is called regularly with the status of the Recording. For example,

```
 async startRecording(callback: onRecordingStatusUpdated) {
    this.isLoading = true

    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      allowsRecordingIOS: true,
      interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
      playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      shouldDuckAndroid: true,
      interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
      playThroughEarpieceAndroid: true
    });
    if (this.recording !== null) {
      // only one recorder is allowed to exist
      this.recording.setOnRecordingStatusUpdate(null);
      this.recording = null;
    }

    const recording = new Audio.Recording();
    await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(this.recordingSettings);
    // ✨✨✨set the callback
    recording.setOnRecordingStatusUpdate(callback);

    this.recording = recording;
    await this.recording.startAsync(); // Will call this._updateScreenForRecordingStatus to update the screen.
    this.isLoading = false
  }
 // 
 startRecording((status => console.log('[onRecording]', status)))
```